# How to list all tags from post / pages

Tags: java, freemarker, jbake

I would like to print tags that related with post / page with Jbake. But, after read the JBake documentation, especially for [Data Model](https://jbake.org/docs/2.6.7/#data_model) documentation so far I'm aware about:

- alltags
- tags
- tagged_posts
- tagged_documents

But, among those list there is no data model for tags that specific to post / page. It's possible to print tags specific to post / page?

I'm using:

- JBake version 2.7.0-rc.4
- Apache Freemarker as the template engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After do trial and error finally I could list all tags from post / page.

JBake documentation for data model is only documented for global data model, so listed below model is for global use and is not what I want.

- alltags
- tags
- tagged_posts
- tagged_documents

The tags for post / page is actually exist within `content` data model. You can access it with `${content.tags}`, this will list all tags that related with post / page that you want.

Now, to print it is the tricky part. Because the `tags` key within `content` model is only exist within `post` / `page` template.

### Print tags on `post` / `page` template.

List all post / page tags is easier when you're working under `post` / `page` template. What you need to do is iterate the `content.tags`.

```
<#list content.tags as tag>
  ${tag}
</#list>
```

### Print tags outside `post` / `page` template.

This situation is when I need to generate `<meta name="keywords" content="" />` on the html head section. I need special handling when the meta keywords rendered outside `post` / `page` template, for example `index.html`.

Because when not in `post` / `page` template the `content` data model only contains two keys: `rootpath` and `type`. So, need special handling like below:

```
<#if (content.tags)?? >
  <#-- Make sure we have tags model inside content -->
  <#list content.tags as tag>
    ${tag}<#sep>, </#sep>
  <#else>
    <#-- in case that your page don't have any tags define, print default value if possible -->
  </#list>
<#else>
  <#-- There is no tags model inside content, print default value if possible -->
</#if>
```